# REST API: Field repository in service required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

I am building a REST API using spring boot with a MYSQL database, my app installs successfully but when running the main application I receive this error

```
2020-06-22 15:40:30.638  WARN 8412 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : 
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 
'itemController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'itemService'; nested exception 
is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 
'itemService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'todoItemRepository'; nested exception 
is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itemRepository':
 Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5b270c70' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator]
 while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5b270c70': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' 
 while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

Following are my files:
Controller:

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/todo")
    public class ItemController {

    @Autowired
    private ItemService itemService;

//methods
}
```

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TODO")
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "itemId")
    private Long itemId;

    //other variables followed by setters and getters
```

service:

```
@Service
public class ItemService {

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository todoItemRepository;

    public Item saveTodoItem(Item item) {

        return todoItemRepository.save(item);

    }
//other methods 
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {

    Item findByItemId(Long itemId);
    List<Item> findByListId(UUID listId);
}
```

Configuration files:

```
public class BasicInitialize extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {
                TnDserviceApplication.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{
                null
        };
    }
}
```

persistence config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.example.TNDservice.config")
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
public class PersistenceConfig {
    // Class which call the application properties
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean bean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        bean.setPackagesToScan("com.example.TNDservice.Entity");
        bean.setHibernateProperties(propertiesForHibernate());
        return bean;
    }
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
     Properties propertiesForHibernate() {
       Properties properties = new Properties();
       properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.ddl-auto", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        hibernateTransactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return hibernateTransactionManager;
    }


}
```

application.propoties

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?user=root
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=1234

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TNDservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TNDservice</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>icm</id>
            <name>Spring Framework Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>RESTservice</finalName>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>


</project>
```

Appreciate any help regarding this matter! Thank you!

Comment: You are using mysql dependency in pom but in application.properties you added driver class of SQLServer. Then, how it will work ? Moreover, project is not properly created.

Answer (score 1):

your dependency shows that you want to connect with mysql database.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But, in database properties, you have provided microsoft sql DB info.

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?user=root
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=1234
```

There is no compatibility to connect 2 diff databases.
see the diff between mysql and microsoft sql database server.

[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-mysql-and-sql-server#:~:text=Both%20MySQL%20and%20SQL%20Server,is%20licensed%20product%20of%20Microsoft.&text=SQL%20Server%20supports%20programming%20languages,Visual%20Basic%2C%20Delphi%2C%20R](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-mysql-and-sql-server#:%7E:text=Both%20MySQL%20and%20SQL%20Server,is%20licensed%20product%20of%20Microsoft.&text=SQL%20Server%20supports%20programming%20languages,Visual%20Basic%2C%20Delphi%2C%20R).